# Ajax repeats header

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to load pages but it repeats the header . here is the plugin i am using

http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/demo.php

here is the jquery call i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.ajaxify').ajaxify();
})
</script>
```

in my ajaify javascript file i have modified the div container an i am able to make ajax call . here is my link

```
<a href="xyz.html"  class="ajaxify"   >xyz</a>
```

everything is working fine except it repeats the header. this xyz.html page is coming and as usuall all pages of website is having same header so it loads after header with header at the top so it has two header .please help

Comment: you should post your mark up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

A. Remove the header code from `xyz.html`

or

B. Remove the existing header from the DOM when the link is clicked.

To remove the existing header from the DOM, you can [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$( '#header' ).remove();
```

where `header` is the ID of the element that contains your header.

Comment: @ george if i will remove the header code from xyz.html then when a user clicks and opens in new tab he will see without header . i dont know how to remove from the DOM.here you can check its working fine    http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/demo.php     here you click on easy way , this plugin dispalys it without header and when we click and open in new window it displays with header http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/example.php?action=theasyway

Comment: @Sujit Tiwari: Please see my updated answer for code to remove the header from the DOM.

Comment: hey it removed the header from the main page also . i just want to remove duplicate header

Comment: i saw your code but its removing the header from entire site , i just want to remove it from the duplicate one

Comment: You need to remove the existing header first, before loading the new one. They have the same div ID (and class, perhaps) so you can't just remove the new one.